# Google Sheets add a Conditional Formatting if values don't exists

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two range of Values in Google Sheets.

```
table1      
Values1 Values2 Values3
1          A    4
2          B    5
3          C    6

table2      
Values1 Values2 Values3
1          A      4
2          B    
3
```

I want to apply a conditional formatting (white formatting characters if the values don't exist in table2.

Expected Results (Applied Conditional Formatting to table 1)

```
Values1 Values2 Values3
1          A       4
2          B    
3
```

How do I do this in google sheets?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question isn't really about programming, but even putting that aside, Google's [documentation for the feature](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) seems to address it ("Use custom formulas with conditional formatting"). Whether it's here or at a sibling site on StackExchange, you should mention what in those instructions has given you difficulty, so that answers can focus on that. It doesn't help you, us, or future readers if this question effectively becomes a request to duplicate Google's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning,
I believe this will answer your question.  Make sure to apply the Conditional Formatting rules to the cells in Table 1 only.

Screenshot of my example:
[image: Screenshot of Spreadsheet]

[image: Screenshot of Conditional Formatting]

Then use the formula (note what range my example covers): =COUNTIF($A$2:$B$9,A1)<2

I used the default green to illustrate that the conditional formatting has actually taken place.

I hope this will get you started.  Lots of resources out there for this sort of thing.  Note the first comment from **yshavit**.  This exact answer (with only the range modified) can be found in Example 1 of Google's documentation.